# How do I add an XElement to a document, avoiding the "incorrectly structured document" error?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

```
        // Remove element with ID of 1
        var userIds = from user in document.Descendants("Id")
                       where user.Value == "1"
                       select user;

        userIds.Remove();

        SaveAndDisplay(document);

        // Add element back
        var newElement = new XElement("Id", "0", 
            new XElement("Balance", "3000"));
        document.Add(newElement);

        SaveAndDisplay(document);
```

The add element back block is the problem. As when it gets to the add it states:

> This operation would create an
>   incorrectly structured document.

What stupid mistake am I making?

**Edit:**

Yes, I was reading as an `XDocument`, not `XElement`. Any advice on when to favour one or the other?

Comment: On a side note, your `newElement` object stores the `Balance` node as a child of `Id`.  This doesn't match your expected XML structure.

Comment: You're right, but you can ignore the xml structure, I thought it was required but I can literally add anything.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add a new element as a child of your document's root.  If so, then you need to change your `Add` statement to the following.

```
var newElement = new XElement("Id", "0", new XElement("Balanace", "3000"));
document.Root.Add(newElement);
```

Adding directly to the document adds another root element, which violates the XML structure.

Answer (score 8):

You're effectively trying to add a new root element, which these objects don't like.  I assume `document` is an XDocument?  Place it further inside the root node, by adding it to the root node.  Use:

`document.Root.Add(newElement)` or 
`document.FirstNode.Add(newElement)`

Comment: Even more correctly: `if (document.Root.FirstNode != null) document.Root.FirstNode.AddAfterSelf(newElement); else document.Root.AddFirst(newElement);`