# Loop for XElement.Parse (in C#)

Tags: c#, html, sql, xml, loops

I'm now creating a program that builds a html document from strings using the `XDocument`. `(XElement.Parse)` I'm using System.Xml and using System.Xml.Linq;

For a good example, I paste a piece of my code:
`...
StringBuilder table_dynamic10 = new StringBuilder();
table_dynamic10.Append("<tr><td class=\"tg-baqh\">" + *VALUE1* + "</td><td class=\"tg-baqh\">" + *VALUE2* + "</td></tr>");
...`

`var xDocument = new XDocument(
...
XElement.Parse(table_dynamic10.ToString())
...`

`*VALUE1*` and `*VALUE2*` will be values from the SQL database.There are several of them, that's why I want to use a `loop` for `table_dynamic10` BUT my `XElement.Parse` allows to display it *only once*.

I do not know how I can solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think XDocument requires a root element. Then, you can have multiple children inside your root element. Hope it helps,

Comment: You don't share the text of the exception, but your question is probably a duplicate of [This operation would create an incorrectly structured document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14081843) and [How do I add an XElement to a document, avoiding the “incorrectly structured document” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2111424).  We need a [mcve], or at least the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception, to be sure.

Comment: Where does parsing XML even come into this? It looks like you're trying to parse XML that you're generating. You don't need to parse XML to write HTML. It's just strings. There's also a [class just for this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) but you probably don't need that either.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); you have some problem X and thought building a “html document from strings” would fix it. For us to help you have to explain what X is.

Answer (score 1):

The intent is a little unclear, but perhaps what you're looking for is something *vaguely* like this:

```
public class WritesRowsOfHtml
{
    public void BeginHtmlDocument(StringBuilder document)
    {
        document.Append("<html><body>");
    }

    public void WriteTable(StringBuilder document, IEnumerable<ThingContainingValues> things)
    {
        document.Append("<table>");
        foreach (var thing in things)
        {
            document.AppendFormat("<tr><td class=\"tg-baqh\">{0}</td><td class=\"tg-baqh\">{1}</td></tr>",
                thing.Value1, thing.Value2);
        }
        document.Append("</table>");
    }

    public void EndHtmlDocument(StringBuilder document)
    {
        document.Append("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

One individual method doesn't have to create the entire document. You can do it in pieces, and then when you've written everything to the `StringBuilder` you can build an XML document from that string. (That's if you actually need an XML document. I'm not sure why you need one.)

This really depends on how complicated the document is. You could do the whole thing, including opening and closing tags, in one method. But if it's complex and you don't want to write giant methods then you could break it up like this.